# Attach Camera to moving Object

Tags: rotation, julia, translation

is it possible to attach the camera on a moving object with GLMakie. Yes I know that I can use update_cam!(), translate_cam!() and rotate_cam!() but is there also another possibility?

I want that if the Object is rotating or translating that the Camera is doing the same movement.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.